# How to run GetMethod.Invoke ? I got error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.

```
public class Parameter : BaseEntity
{
    ...
    ...

    public override void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parameter>(opt =>
        {
            opt.ToTable("Parameter");
            opt.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            opt.Property(x => x.AutoId).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
            opt.HasAlternateKey(x => x.AutoId);
        });
    }
}


public class DataContext<T> : DbContext where T : BaseEntity
{
    ...
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        t.GetMethod("Map").Invoke(this, new object[] { modelBuilder }); // this line *****
    }
}
```

T is called as Parameter class. And (// this line *****) side gives me error.

System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.

How can i run this ?

Comment: Well, you are calling it with `this`, and `this` is not a `Parameter` but a `DataContext<T>`, that's why it doesn't work. Do you have an instance of `Parameter` that you intended to use instead?

Comment: Actually i tried `t` instead of `this`. I got same error. I want to write T there bcs it has to be generic. I have x20 class more like `Parameter` and they have `Map` void. I have to call them to run this project.

Comment: Accoring to your code `t` is the `Type` of `T`, not an instance of `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), something like the following (and even the argument type is irrelevant), your problem immediately becomes apparent:

```
class ArgumentType
{

}

class Foo
{
    public void Bar(ArgumentType argument)
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type t = typeof(Foo);

        var argument = new ArgumentType();

        t.GetMethod("Bar").Invoke(this, new object[] { argument });
    }
}
```

You're invoking the method on `this`, which is *not* a `Foo` (or a `T` in your case), so you get that exception.

To fix the code, you need to instantiate `T` and invoke the method on that:

```
var instance = new Foo(); // or new T() in your case

t.GetMethod("Bar").Invoke(instance, new object[] { argument });
```

You also have to constrain `T` to `new()` for that to work, to indicate that type arguments passed for `T` have to have a parameterless constructor, so you can instantiate it there.

Comment: I got this! I created instance by using `Activator`. Thanks for your idea so much.